# Dynamic stylesheets implemented by express middleware

Tags: node.js, dynamic, express, middleware, stylesheet

I would like to be able to dynamically add a stylesheet from inside my routes to a global stylesheet array using express middleware.

I have come up with this gist https://gist.github.com/1375882 but each page refresh just continues to add the route's stylesheet list to the end of the array. How can I keep it from doing this?

Comment: is that the full code for your app?

Comment: no, just enough to show the example of how it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code will solve your problem:

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express.createServer()

// Function to push formatted style
// paths onto our stylesheet variable
var addStyles = function(res, styles) {
  var temp = []
  styles.forEach(function(style){
    temp.push('/stylesheets/' + style + '.css')
  })
  temp = res.local('styles').concat(temp)
  res.local('styles', temp)
}

// Middleware that adds default styles
var buildStyles = function(default_styles){
  var styles = []
  // format our default style paths
  default_styles.forEach(function(style){
    styles.push('/stylesheets/' + style + '.css')
  })

  return function(req, res, next) {
    res.local('styles', styles)
    next()
  }
}

// Configure our middleware
app.configure(function(){
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
  app.set('view engine', 'jade')
  // Call our custom middleware passing in
  // an array of global stylesheets to use
  app.use(buildStyles(['global']))
})

app.get('/',function(req, res){
  // Add forms.css and user/login.css stylesheet dynamically
  addStyles(res, ['forms','user/login'])
  res.json(res.local('styles'))
  //res.render('home')
})

app.listen(8080)
```

Comment: Thanx! I was actually able to solve it and add more functionality by creating a module with a factory. Instead of pushing to the styles array inline it builds the array once at runtime. Same as you've done here, but now I can also dynamically add javascript sources and meta tags :)